# How to move an image to the top of my web page? (HTML)

Tags: html, css, image, header, blogs

I need help with my HTML code for my website. I'm having difficulties placing an image background on my webpage. The header keeps blocking my image off. (Image below)[image]

Right above the blue wings, it keeps getting blocked off.

Below is my HMTL code for the web page.

```
<style>
  body { 
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/KyYCMrk.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top; 
    max-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide the markup for your example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the css you posted seems fine

Comment: By markup you mean the entire code?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/h2b4gs0j/  It looks like you have other markup/styling which is obscuring part of the image.  The screen shot in the question is the top of the image, but something else appears to be blocking it.

Comment: Would you like to see the rest of my code?

Comment: The HTML is what he is referring to Hypertext "Markup" Language :)

Comment: Here's the entire markup for the web page: http://pastebin.com/573FHJiu